# mvn clean install is not working from command line but works fine in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, command, xtext

I created a new project wizard with plain maven directory structure in Eclipse with Xtext 2.9.1. I can run "mvn clean install" inside eclipse however when I try to run it from command line (I am using Windows 7). I get the following error. It says there is a bug in Maven itself. Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant
not present
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:44)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java
:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactor
yToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70
)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionLi
stenerStackCallback.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleMana
ger.java:134)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionLi
stenerStackCallback.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStac
kCallback.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.ja
va:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToIni
tializableAdapter.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFact
oryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactory
Adapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProvider
Adapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.EntryListAdapter$ValueIterator.next(EntryListAdapter.java:111)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getLifecycleParticipants(DefaultMaven.java:540)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:268)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/tycho/core/maven/TychoMavenLifecycleP
articipant : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.ja
va:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:100)
        ... 37 more
[ERROR] Internal error: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.
maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant not present
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.23.1, parent: sun.misc.Launch
er$AppClassLoader@12360be0]
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.23.1, parent: sun.misc.Launch
er$AppClassLoader@12360be0]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant annotated with @com.google
.inject.name.Named(value=TychoMavenLifecycleListener)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1 error: org/eclipse/tycho/core/maven/TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant : Unsupported major.min
or version 51.0
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice
 provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.Ty
choMavenLifecycleParticipant not present
  at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.23.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$App
ClassLoader@12360be0]
  at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.23.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$App
ClassLoader@12360be0]
  while locating org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant annotated with @com.google.injec
t.name.Named(value=TychoMavenLifecycleListener)

1 error
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.Ty
choMavenLifecycleParticipant not present
  at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.23.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$App
ClassLoader@12360be0]
  at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.23.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$App
ClassLoader@12360be0]
  while locating org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant annotated with @com.google.injec
t.name.Named(value=TychoMavenLifecycleListener)

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.EntryListAdapter$ValueIterator.next(EntryListAdapter.java:111)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getLifecycleParticipants(DefaultMaven.java:540)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:268)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleP
articipant not present
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:44)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java
:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactor
yToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70
)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionLi
stenerStackCallback.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleMana
ger.java:134)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionLi
stenerStackCallback.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStac
kCallback.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.ja
va:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToIni
tializableAdapter.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFact
oryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactory
Adapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProvider
Adapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/tycho/core/maven/TychoMavenLifecycleP
articipant : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.ja
va:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:100)
        ... 37 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
cles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Comment: `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`, you are probably using a different JRE/JDK from command line. Is the default JRE/JDK in the command line the same as the one you are using in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I just checked. They are same.

Comment: Can you please share you pom.xml file?

Comment: Does this thread doesn't fix your problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error. What is your JRE/JDK ?

Comment: In the command line are you sure that you write your command `mvn clean install` Under `~\workspace\YourProject` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime.

To fix the actual problem you should try to either run the Java code with a newer version of Java JRE or specify the target parameter to the Java compiler to instruct the compiler to create code compatible with earlier Java versions.

For example, in order to generate class files compatible with Java 1.7, use the following command line:

```
javac -target 1.7 HelloWorld.java
```

With newer versions of the Java compiler you are likely to get a warning about the bootstrap class path not being set. More information about this error is available in 
[oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source).

Another good explanation how to fix your problem [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-solve-unsupported-majorminor-version-51-java.html).